# Nameserver setup Bind

Tags: bind, nameserver

I have setup a domain and nameservers as per below, but when I dig the domain, it is not working.

The setup is as follows: I want a domain named iheartlotto.com, and the nameservers to be ns1.iheartlotto.com and ns2.iheartlotto.com.

iheartlotto.com is meant to be on 148.251.181.168
ns1.iheartlotto.com to be on 148.251.197.217
ns2.iheartlotto.com to be on 148.251.197.218

When I `dig ns1.iheartlotto.com`, it works fine and I get as part of the output:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
ns1.iheartlotto.com.    86400   IN  A   148.251.197.217
```

The above is correct.

BUT, when I  `dig iheartlotto.com` returns the below. Note that IN A is blank.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> iheartlotto.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20497
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;iheartlotto.com.       IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
iheartlotto.com.    10800   IN  SOA iheartlotto.com. hostmaster.iheartlotto.com. 2014101004 10800 3600 604800 10800

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Oct 10 21:26:53 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 80
```

The actual files I have are:

**181.251.148.in-addr.arpa**

```
$TTL    86400

@       IN      SOA     iheartlotto.com. hostmaster.iheartlotto.com. (
                        2014101000      ; Serial
                        10800   ; Refresh
                        3600    ; Retry
                        604800  ; Expire
                        10800 ) ; Minimum

                 IN NS   iheartlotto.com.
168              IN PTR  iheartlotto.com.
```

**197.251.148.in-addr.arpa**

```
$TTL    86400

@       IN      SOA     iheartlotto.com. hostmaster.iheartlotto.com. (
                        2014101002      ; Serial
                        10800   ; Refresh
                        3600    ; Retry
                        604800  ; Expire
                        10800 ) ; Minimum

                 IN NS   iheartlotto.com.
217              IN PTR  ns1.iheartlotto.com.
218              IN PTR  ns2.iheartlotto.com.
```

iheartlotto.com.db

```
$TTL    86400

@       IN      SOA     iheartlotto.com. hostmaster.iheartlotto.com. (
                        2014101004       ; Serial
                        10800   ; Refresh
                        3600    ; Retry
                        604800  ; Expire
                        10800 ) ; Minimum

iheartlotto.com.            IN NS   ns1.iheartlotto.com.
iheartlotto.com.            IN NS   ns2.iheartlotto.com.

ns1.iheartlotto.com.        IN A    148.251.197.217
ns2.iheartlotto.com.        IN A    148.251.197.218

iheartlotto.com             IN A 148.251.181.168
```

named.conf.local

```
include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "181.251.148.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/181.251.148.in-addr.arpa";
};
zone "197.251.148.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/197.251.148.in-addr.arpa";
};
zone "iheartlotto.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/iheartlotto.com.db";
};
```

How can I have **dig iheartlotto.com** return an A record (along with all the other correct info), like it does for dig ns1.iheartlotto.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a PERIOD after iheartlotto.com in your forward zone:

```
 iheartlotto.com.            IN A 148.251.181.168
```